# Converting IBuffer to Buffer array

Tags: windows-8

I'm writing a JavaScript windows store app. My requirement is to read a file which is available locally  and get arraybuffer or Uint8array as the response.

I tried using "Windows.Storage.FileIO.readBufferAsync(file)" but that is giving me an IBuffer object.

1. Is there an API that reads a file and gives me arraybuffer?
2. How do i convert "IBuffer" to "arraybuffer" ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.aspx), for instance:

```
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/textfile.txt")).then(
        function (myFile) {
            Windows.Storage.FileIO.readBufferAsync(myFile).done(
                function (buffer) {
                    var myArray = new Uint8Array(buffer.length);

                    var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.fromBuffer(buffer);
                    dataReader.readBytes(myArray)
                    dataReader.close();
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

Comment: you're welcome...can I ask that you mark the question as accepted.  Click the "See More" link under [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#link-howtoask) in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.copyToByteArray(IBuffer)

this returns Uint8Array (byte array)